# cURL and Error 411 (Content Length)

Tags: json, curl

I'm using cURL to connect to a remote host.  Some of my commands execute just fine (like authentication via POST and pulling information via GET).  I'm getting a weird error when trying to use a POST to add information with regards to content length.  This is my syntax;

```
curl -k -i -b sessionid -X POST https://hostname/BeyondTrust/api/public/v3/Workgroups/apiTest/Assets?AssetName=string&DnsName=string&DomainName=string -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Authorization: PS-Auth key=b8e1...2c27; runas=userName; pwd=[password]" -d ""
```

This is my output;

```
[1] 58164
[2] 58165
-bash: -H: command not found
[2]+  Done                    DnsName=string
HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Fri, 27 Oct 2017 14:29:12 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 344

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I've researched it, and this is a common problem, apparently. `-d ""` does not fix and have tried `--ignore-content-length` and `Content-Length: 0` in the headers, but I still have the same issue.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: the `[1] 58164` and `[2] 58165` indicates a process that completed (I think) -- 58164 was the process ID of the terminated process. When you see that it means bash split your command up into multiple little commands. Sure sign of a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the URL because it contains some special shell characters.

This output tells you something went wrong:

```
[1] 58164
[2] 58165
-bash: -H: command not found
[2]+  Done                    DnsName=string
```

Your command got split into multiple jobs and resulted in some errors because of the `&` in the URL's query string.

Putting the URL in double-quotes `"` will fix the issue.

```
curl -k -i -b sessionid \
-X POST \
"https://hostname/BeyondTrust/api/public/v3/Workgroups/apiTest/Assets?AssetName=string&DnsName=string&DomainName=string"
```

This way your URL will be interpreted properly and the shell won't try to start it in the [background](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes#starting-processes).